# Send an array in the page URL

Tags: arrays, http, get

I send an array as a string in the URL of the page (query string), using GET method. Is that wrong? And if it is wrong, could you please tell me why? Is it a security issue or what?

Thank you all.

Comment: It's not necessarily wrong, it just becomes wrong if your array is big. Browsers and implementations often put limits on the size of a GET request (and very, very long URLs are pretty ugly anyway).

Comment: Your answer is very convincing. Thanks for your interest :D

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add your elements to your URL with

```
file.html?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

and so on.

Comment: That's what I'll do mostly. Thanks for your interest :D